# C++ What are the differences between std::lock and std::unique_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking

I came into a situation where I need to lock a resource (a `std::queue`) between two processing threads.

The first thread needs to `push` data to `std::queue`, while the second thread is going to `pop` that data out of the queue and process it.

I need to make sure both threads will not compete for my `std::queue`.

As this is my first time using C++ locks, I came into different approaches: `std::lock` and `std::unique_lock`, but I don´t know which one to choose...

What is the difference between `std::lock` and `std::unique_lock` and how they should be used.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::lock` is an *algorithm* that locks a *collection of lockable objects* all at once in a specific way that avoids deadlocks.

`std::unique_lock` is a class template that wraps a mutex and can be used as a scoped lock guard, similar to `std::lock_guard`, but more powerful than the latter (it is itself lockable, can be unlocked early and can be moved around).

You probably want neither of those, but instead just use the good old `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: In particular, `std::lock` is often used with a bunch of `unique_lock`s constructed with `std::defer_lock`.